# Forgot Password Form no longer works

Tags: php

Okay so after my host updated their CP I had to change all pages extension to .php and so some more changes. Now the following code won't work for me (yes I know mysql_query is outdated, using PHP 5.3)

```
<?php 
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Allowing MySQL Connection - Include_Check has to be TRUE
if($_POST['submit']=='Send') {
$email=$_POST['email'];
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$status = "OK";
$msg="";
if (!stristr($email,"@") OR !stristr($email,".")) {
Header("Location: login_panel/nosent.php");
$status= "NOTOK";}

if($status=="OK") {  // If e-mail is valid, status stays the same: query time!
$query="SELECT email,usr FROM tz_members WHERE email = '$email'";
$st=mysql_query($query);
$recs=mysql_num_rows($st);
$row=mysql_fetch_object($st);
$em=$row->email;// Switching $email to $em for the query.
 if ($recs == 0) { // $recs is 0, that means that address doesn't exist. Tell the guy to register ? Yes plz.
// Display the message
 Header("Location: login_panel/nosent.php");
exit; }

$pass = rand(1000,9999);
// Using the functions.php public: sendMail
send_mail(  'administrator@cod5showtime.url.ph',
                        $_POST['email'],
                        'Username: '.$row->usr,
                        'Password: '.$pass); 
mysql_query("UPDATE tz_members SET $row->pass = md5($pass) WHERE email = $email");
Header("Location: login_panel/sent.php");
}
}
?>
```

And HTML:

```
<form action="forgot.php" method="post">
<div class="grey">E-Mail Address:</div><br>
<input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="40" value=""><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></div>
</form>
```

While changing passwords which has a similar script works perfectly, resetting emails doesn't work.

I also have a problem. the Headers aren't sent, but I get no warning messages, any ideas why?

Comment: Use quotes `WHERE email = '$email'` and don't use MD5 nor `mysql_*`

Comment: Wait for answers to start pouring in. I can't seem to find my can opener right now.

Comment: Adding the two `'` didn't fix anything @ Fred-ii. I belive this is an important information: PHP headers refuse to get sent in this page.

Comment: Well, that would be "one" of the things that needed to be done. I didn't say it would fix everything. About the headers not being sent; might have something to do with `SET $row->pass` (or `$row->pass = md5($pass)`) or are you talking about the header above that?

Comment: And you have a `send_mail()` function? Usually it's `mail()` but if that's what you're using.

Comment: Yes, the mail is being sent. As of the headers, I am not talking about the email ones, I am talking about `Header("Location: ...");`

Comment: You have 3x `Header("Location:...` which one? Or, do none work?

Comment: None of them works, but the email is sent, also MySQL stuffs aren't updated. This is really strange, haven't touched the code and it was working perfectly before.

Comment: If there was an upgrade done and if PHP was updated too, chances are that `mysql_*` functions are no longer available (deprecated/deleted in new PHP version). Seems to be the most likely scenario.

Comment: Still using PHP 5.3 which allows mysql_* function, and the trick is a similar query works in other pages such as changing email/password, that's by far the strangest thing I ever stumbled on.

Comment: I can't spot anything else. I've looked it over multiple times, and can't come up with anything else.

Comment: This is really strange, all that happened after I changed file extension from .html to .php.

Comment: Can you try adding `exit;` after `$status= "NOTOK";`

Comment: Oh wait a minute. You have an `AddHandler` or similar in your `.htaccess` to treat `.html` as PHP?